# Do recruiters intentionally have multiple phone numbers?

Tags: recruitment

I've discovered two recruiters now - who everytime they call me, they call from a different number.

This makes it difficult to tag their number with the name to know who's calling - it's always an unknown number.

I asked one, and they told me that it was something to do with their telecom infrastructure.

Is this plausible - or is this just a mechanism for getting you to answer the phone?

Comment: It's likely just something that they do to get you to answer the phone or it could just be another person from the same recruitment agency with a very similar but different number

Comment: I have had recruitment agents call me from their office phone or their mobile. Have you ruled this possibility out?

Comment: Yes, it is most probably their telephone infrastructure.

Answer (score 6):

They most likely use call center software. The result from that is an ever-rotating phone number from the pool the company owns.